# jQuery Steps new steps being added to a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-steps

I'm using the [jQuery Steps wizard library](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) to process orders from customers.

The default examples come with four steps at most, which look good. However, when I add a fifth step, it doesn't fit in the same line and goes to a second line.

Here's a screenshot where you can clearly see what I'm talking about:

[image]

I would like to have all five steps in the same line, so I have been trying to reduce the width of the steps hoping that would do it.

Here's my CSS:

```
/*
    Common 
*/

.wizard,
.tabcontrol
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a
{
    outline: 0;
}

.wizard ul,
.tabcontrol ul
{
    list-style: none !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wizard ul > li,
.tabcontrol ul > li
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Accessibility */
.wizard > .steps .current-info,
.tabcontrol > .steps .current-info
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}

.wizard > .content > .title,
.tabcontrol > .content > .title
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}



/*
    Wizard
*/

.wizard > .steps
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

.wizard > .steps .number
{
    font-size: 1.429em;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li,
.wizard > .actions > ul > li
{
    float: left;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps > ul > li
{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard > .steps a,
.wizard > .steps a:hover,
.wizard > .steps a:active
{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .steps .disabled a,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:active
{
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .current a,
.wizard > .steps .current a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .current a:active
{
    background: #595959;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .done a,
.wizard > .steps .done a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .done a:active
{
    background: #808080;
    color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .steps .error a,
.wizard > .steps .error a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .error a:active
{
    background: #ff3111;
    color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .content
{
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em;
    min-height: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard.vertical > .content
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2.5% 0.5em 2.5%;
    width: 65%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul
{
    list-style: disc !important;
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul > li
{
    display: list-item;
}

.wizard > .content > .body > iframe
{
    border: 0 none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input.error
{
    background: rgb(251, 227, 228);
    border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;
    color: #8a1f11;
}

.wizard > .content > .body label
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.wizard > .content > .body label.error
{
    color: #8a1f11;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.wizard > .actions
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
    width: 95%;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul > li
{
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions > ul > li
{
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.wizard > .actions a,
.wizard > .actions a:active
{
    background: #808080;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .actions a:hover {
    background: #595959;
}

.wizard > .actions .disabled a,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:active
{
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa;
}

.wizard > .loading
{
}

.wizard > .loading .spinner
{
}



/*
    Tabcontrol
*/

.tabcontrol > .steps
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li
{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 1px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li:hover
{
    background: #edecec;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current
{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    padding: 0 0 1px 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a
{
    color: #595959;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current > a
{
    padding: 15px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.tabcontrol > .content
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul
{
    list-style: disc !important;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul > li
{
    display: list-item;
}

@media (max-width: 600px)
{
    .wizard > .steps > ul > li
    {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .wizard > .steps a,
    .wizard > .steps a:hover,
    .wizard > .steps a:active
    {
        margin-top: 0.5em;
    }

    .wizard.vertical > .steps,
    .wizard.vertical > .actions
    {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .wizard.vertical > .content
    {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
        width: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px)
{
    .wizard > .steps > ul > li
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.wizard .content {
    min-height: 100px;
}
.wizard .content > .body {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

My first thought was changing the first few lines:

```
.wizard,
.tabcontrol
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to

```
.wizard,
.tabcontrol
{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but although that did reduce the width of the steps by half, it didn't put them in the same line and simply had them look like this:

[image]

My knowledge of CSS is very limited and I'm not sure what I am supposed to change so that the wizard looks how I want. Any help?

Comment: It would be easier if you would do a fiddle. Apart from this now i think the problem is that the box elements are still too wide to fit in your layout. if you put 5 in a row the width should be 100/5 - 4xmargin-right (space you want to have between them) = x% (where the last element shouldnt have a margin). This is the width you should be using so they always are in the same line. What happens on your last screenshot is because the box is too small for the text. You can rather change the font-size on smaller screens with CSS/Media Queries or make the other boxes fit to the height using Jquery.

Comment: @MarcelW Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I solved it now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was modifying the wrong CSS block, all I had to do was update this:

```
.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 25%;
}
```

to this:

```
.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 20%;
}
```